# Does this CNC machine exist?

Tags: 3d-printing, cnc

About ten years ago I had an idea for a cnc machine that was meant to basically use multiple axis to airbrush finished milled or printed 3d objects. I still have my detail drawings i worked up for it.

I have been googling all day but I cannot find anything like it. Is there such a machine?

Comment: I'd guess a six axis robot is what you'd want.

Comment: so a CNC paint application? I think in automotive it's a generic robot arm application

Comment: What I've learned is there is a CNC machine for everything, but they are not necessarily mass produced and may be custom or made-to-order. Could easily be one of those products only marketed and known by those who need and can afford them.

Comment: Robot arms aka CNC exist for painting and many other tasks. One has even been programmed to play pool (billiards).

Comment: These are plain ole industrial robots, you've been beaten to the punch about 50 years ago.

Comment: that a device exists should not be sufficient reason to avoid making something you need.  perhaps your rendition can fill a niche or suit your immediate needs.